# How could I build tensorflow-serving-api myself？

Tags: api, tensorflow-serving

I have added some custom code in serving and I want to build my own tensorflow-serving-api for the customized serving, especially ReloadConfig API. But I have no idea how to build it myself. It seems that I could only install `tensorflow-serving-api` from pip. 
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
# Pull the latest source code (or pick a release branch)
$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving .

# Make changes you'd want to make

# Build the pip package using the latest nightly docker build
$ tools/bazel_in_docker.sh bazel build --color=yes tensorflow_serving/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

# Run the pip package builder using the latest nightly docker build
$ tools/bazel_in_docker.sh bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package $(pwd)/pip

# Install the package that has your custom code
$ pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade $(pwd)/pip/tensorflow_serving*.whl

# Clean up your extracted folder (optional)
$ rm -rf $(pwd)/pip
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I followed your suggestion and build "build_pip_package" successfully. But after I run it, nothing new appeared in the folder I assigned. This is my command "bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package ./tmp/", and there was nothing in "./tmp"

Comment: I have figured out why I failed. The argument must be absolute path. It worked. Thanks.